# How to duplicate data with the same name?

Tags: angular, typescript

My code:

```
this.temp1.push(this.json);

for(let i=0; i<this.temp1.length; i++){
    if(this.temp1[i].name == this.json.name){       
        this.orderList[i] = this.json;
        this.DBorder[i] = this.order_json;      
    }
    else{
        this.orderList.push(this.json);
        this.DBorder.push(this.order_json);
    }
}
```

My first input data:

```
[{"name":"Pad-Thai", "price":10,"amount":1,"total":10}]
```

My second input data (with a new amount):

```
[{"name":"Pad-Thai", "price":10,"amount":3,"total":30}]
```

Current result:

```
[{"name":"Pad-Thai", "price":10,"amount":3,"total":30},
{"name":"Pad-Thai", "price":10,"amount":3,"total":30}]
```

Expected result:

```
[{"name":"Pad-Thai", "price":10,"amount":3,"total":30}]
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. I don't get it. Please review my [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71534849/revisions)-

Comment: @Christian Sorry for baffling question and thank you for your edit, I'm not good at English.

Comment: I hope I got it in my edit. The different amount confuses me. The word duplicate doesn't seem to match here. Do you want to limit the result?

Comment: @Christian Can you look at my new edit question. I hope you understand more.

Comment: Does your current result display `"amount":3` twice? or both 1 and 3 ?

Comment: @Christian Twice

Answer (score 2):

1. Check name and update if exist else inset while adding new object in
   array.

   ```js
       const obj1 = { "name": "Pad-Thai", "price": 10, "amount": 1, "total": 10 };
           const obj2 = { "name": "Pad-Thai", "price": 10, "amount": 3, "total": 30 };
           const obj3 = { "name": "Some-Other-Dish", "price": 20, "amount": 2, "total": 40 };

           let temp1 = [];
           function addItem(obj) {
               let index = temp1.findIndex(x => x.name === obj.name);
               if (index > -1) {
                   temp1[index] = obj;
               } else {
                   temp1.push(obj);
               }
           }
           addItem(obj1);
           addItem(obj2);
           addItem(obj3);
           console.log('temp1 : ', temp1);
   ```
2. If you have already added obj with same name then you can remove
   using for loop and find index or reduce loop

   ```js
       const output = [
           { "name": "Pad-Thai", "price": 10, "amount": 1, "total": 10 },
           { "name": "Pad-Thai", "price": 10, "amount": 3, "total": 30 },
           { "name": "Some-Other-Dish", "price": 20, "amount": 2, "total": 40 }
       ]

       let temp1 = [];
       output.forEach(obj => {
           let index = temp1.findIndex(x => x.name === obj.name);
           if (index > -1) {
               temp1[index] = obj;
           } else {
               temp1.push(obj);
           } 
       });
       console.log('temp1 : ', temp1);
   ```

Comment: Thank a lot. You save my life. I love you broooooo Sahil

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input1 = [{
  "name": "Pad-Thai",
  "price": 10,
  "amount": 3,
  "total": 10
}]
const input2 = [{
  "name": "Pad-Thai",
  "price": 10,
  "amount": 3,
  "total": 30
}];

function merge(existing, update, identifier) {
  const mapped = update.reduce((acc, el) => {
    return { ...acc,
      [el[identifier]]: el
    };
  }, {});

  return existing.map(el => {
    const altered = { ...el,
      ...mapped[el[identifier]]
    };
    
    delete mapped[el[identifier]];

    return altered;
  }).concat(Object.values(mapped));
}

console.log(merge(input1, input2, "name"));
```